# The Most recent post will only show at the bottom of the page in hugo

Tags: hugo

I am trying to add the most recent post to _index.md. When I put in the code on the home page it only shows it at the bottom of the page. If it does show it where I want to go then there will be dupilcation at the bottom of the page. The shortcode is

```
{{ range .Site.RegularPages.ByDate | first 5 }}
<li><a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a></li>
{{end}}
```

And in my _index.md I have

```
# Posts

{{< post >}}



# My and Other Projects

[Github](https://github.com/Luharion)



[Cyberscecurity blog](https://rebootcyber.xyz)
```

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

I tried to move the {{< post >}} and nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<li>` items need to be wrapped in an `<ul>`. Now you will get:

```
<p><li>...</li><li>...</li><li>...</li><li>...</li></p>
```

The rest seems good to me.